# Do I need a transit vsa in Kuwait; what about checked baggage?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, transit-visas, kuwait

I am traveling to India from Athens on Aegean Airlines and transiting in Kuwait for the onward flight on Kuwait Airlines. The layover is about 4.5 hours.

Do I need a transit visa? How will I collect my checked luggage from Aegean Airlines. Will the staff provide help if the baggage counter is after immigration?

Answer (score 2):

As you need leave the sterile area to collect and recheck your luggage, you do require a visa, as you would have to go through [Immigration](https://www.dgca.gov.kw/en/travellers/traveller-information/arrival-procedures/hospitality-services).

When you say staff, if you mean airline personnel, no, but there are fee-based [meet-and-greet services](https://www.kuwaitairways.com/en/is/maraheb) which can be booked in advance. In that case, you would be able to remain airside and Transit Without Visa, according to Timatic:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours. In case of transit connections beyond 8 hours, passengers must remain airside and be accommodated in the airport transit hotel.

The [Kuwait Ministry of the Interior](https://www.e.gov.kw/sites/kgoEnglish/Pages/HomePage.aspx) notes that

> A transit visa, valid for a maximum stay of 7 days, can be obtained from a Kuwait Consulate abroad or from a Port Authority in Kuwait. The fee is KD 2.

In Athens, the Kuwaiti Embassy is at Marathonodromou Street 27, Palaio Psychico.

Comment: Huh. So for layovers over 8 hours you need to stay airside, but *shorter* layovers let you pass through immigration??

Comment: No. From what I understand 8 hours are granted in general by air/airports regulations, while the 24h are by the specific Kuwait transit regulation.